# How to specify locale for CompletionService.GetDescriptionAsync result?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I need to specify locale for the result of `CompletionService.GetDescriptionAsync`.

When I call `GetDescriptionAsync` it returns a correct description but in the same language (locale) my Windows runs at, but I would like to specify e.g. new CultureInfo( "en-US" ).

```
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var project = workspace.AddProject( projectInfo );
Document document = workspace.AddDocument( project.Id, "MyCode.cs", SourceText.From( __code__ ) );
CompletionService completionService = CompletionService.GetService( document );
CompletionList completions = completionService.GetCompletionsAsync( document, __positionInTheCode__ ).Result;

if ( completions != null )
  foreach ( CompletionItem completionItem in completions.Items )
  {
    string description = completionService.GetDescriptionAsync( document, completionItem ).Result.Text;
    ...
  }
```

As I am running Czech Windows it returns e.g. for `Console.Beep`:

```
"void Console.Beep() (+1  přetížení)"
```

But I would like to get English version:

```
"void Console.Beep() (+1  overload)"
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the culture of the current thread (i.e. `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`)?

Comment: In the meantime, I had the same idea, but unfortunately it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the setting of `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` is the solution.

Comment: Still does not work for C# keywords. Their description “keyword” stays in the current Windows culture (language).